# app controller in my own helper cake php?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How I use App controller methods or properties in my own helper method in cake php 2.X?
I have method called `get_lan()` in App controller and this is my helper but when i run get error message:

```
Error: Call to undefined function get_lan() 
File: C:\wamp\www\app\View\Helper\current_langHelper.php    
Line: 8"
```

Code:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class current_langHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $helpers = array('Html');

    public function current_lang()
    {
        var_dump(get_lan());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helpers do not call Controller methods. In other words, the Helper does not "see" the Controller members. The Controller should pass information to the View/Helper via the set() method. You could have your get_lang() method (probably better to name it setLang()) to pass the language to the view, something like:

```
private setLang(){ $this->set('lang',$selectedLanguage); }
```

You could then use this variable in your view using:

```
var_dump($lang);
```